# Rounding doubles to the nearest whole number in Java?

Tags: java, double, rounding

How do I round my numbers of `output += Math.pow(baseUno, powernumber)+ " ";` to the nearest whole number?

They always give me an `output` of, for example, **1.0 or 2.0**. How do you round these so that they would simply result as **1 and 2**?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class level7Module1
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{

String base, power, output = " "; //user inputs, and the output variable
double baseUno, powerUno, basenum = 0, powernum = 0; //user inputs parsed so they can be used in mathematical equations

DecimalFormat noDigits = new DecimalFormat("0");

 // oneDigit.format(variablename)


base = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter your prefered base, a number between 1 and 14: \nPress 'q' to quit."); //User input
    if (base.equals("q"))
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Goodbye!");
    System.exit(0); //quits
    }

baseUno = Integer.parseInt(base);
// basenum = noDigits.format(baseUno);

if (baseUno <= 0)
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Really? Why would you try to trick me? ):");
System.exit(0);
}
if (baseUno > 14)
{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"That wasn't cool. Take some time to think about this \nand\nthen\ntry\nagain.\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nJerk.");
System.exit(0);
}

//I chose 0 and 14 because on my monitor the combination of 14 and 14 filled up the entire screen, so I limited to things
 //that would fit on my monitor :)

power = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "How many numbers of this base would you like? Between 1 and 14 again, please.\nPress 'q' to quit.");

if (power.equals("q"))
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Goodbye!");
    System.exit(0);
    }

powerUno = Integer.parseInt(power);
// powernum = noDigits.format(powerUno);

if (powerUno <= 0)
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Really? Why would you try to trick me? ):");
    System.exit(0);
    }
if (powerUno > 14)
    {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"That wasn't cool. Take some time to think about this \nand\nthen\ntry\nagain.\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nJerk.");
    System.exit(0);
    }

for (int powernumber=0; powernumber!=powerUno; powernumber++) //Set the number of powers done to 0, then until it's "powernum" input, it keeps going.
{
output += Math.pow(baseUno, powernumber)+ " "; //Output is the basenum to the power of powernum plus a space, then repeats condition above.
}

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your numbers are: " + output); //Giving the users their outputs

}
}
```

Comment: can't you just cast the returnrd double to int ??

Comment: [Math.round()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29)? eventually casting the result, which is a `long`, to `int`?

Comment: I'd recommend to reduce the amount of code to the relevant parts in order to make it easier to other users to understand what your question is about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the simplest approach change this line :
`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your numbers are: " + output);`

 to

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Your numbers are: " + (int)output);`

 just type caste the result to `int`